# Facebook Open Graph Namespace?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am implementing Opengraph tags into my site and must I use the namespaces provided by Facebook? I am a bit confused as I have seen a couple different things here is an example they give. Must I use this exactly?

```
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Or I need to use only the first?

Comment: Very related to this question, answered by FB stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687/open-graph-namespace-declaration-html-with-xmlns-or-head-prefix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the Facebook namespace if you are going to use Facebook specific tags, like `fb:admins`, etc. Otherwise, you can use just the `og` namespace.

Comment: Thanks, is it a big deal to leave both in there even if I do not use both all the time? Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not a big deal at all to leave both in. You're just letting the XML interpreter know that you [may be using these namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the help and specifying!