# Facebook comments count IE8 innerHTML error

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8

On Internet Explorer 8, on pages where there are comments count tags like `<fb:comments-count href="<%= item_url(@item) %>"></fb:comments-count>`, there will be error in Internet Explorer 8.

> Could not set innerHTML: unknown runtime error.
>   Line: 40, Character: 327
>   http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

All other Facebook plugins (like button, comments box) works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the facebook namespace declaration have to be at the head level.

I changed from

```
<html>
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">
```

to

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">
```

and the errors disappeared.

I was following [Open Graph namespace declaration: HTML with XMLNS or head prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687/open-graph-namespace-declaration-html-with-xmlns-or-head-prefix) but the use-prefix-all-the-way clearly has some issue with ie8.

**Update**

I realized that I am also at fault in using the `<fb:comments-count>` tag by mistake, while I was using the HTML5 `<div class="fb-comments-count">` tag in all other places.

If I leave the namespace declaration as it was, but use the correct HTML5 comments tag, then error will also disappear too.