# How do you clear the Open Graph cache of an URL on Telegram?

Tags: telegram

When I send a new link on Telegram, it automatically reads [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) data of the URL and generates a preview of the page.

When the Open Graph data of the same page changes, though, Telegram doesn't update its preview: it has cached the old Open Graph data!

How do you clear the Open Graph cache?

#### Preview Example:

For the URL `https://asp.net/` Telegram is reading the following tags:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Microsoft">
<meta property="og:title" content="ASP.NET | Open-source web framework for .NET">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://dotnet.microsoft.com/images/redesign/social/large.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript." />
```

And is generating the following preview:

[image]

Comment: send another link to redirect to your desired link, Maybe works.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

#### Use [@webpagebot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot)

You can send the link [up to 10] you want to update to this `Bot` and it will scan your site and generate the new `image thumbnail`, `site name` and `description`.

> Note: *You may need to restart your Telegram client to see the updates*

Images are cached too. Update them the same way. Be sure they're specified using [Open Graph](http://opengraphprotocol.org) but note you [**do not need**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943451/meaning-of-html-prefix-attribute-open-graph-protocol#comment79763316_36229681) to use the `prefix` attribute on your `html` tag to define the OG namespace.

---

#### Second solution:

Use a pattern like the following pattern for your web address:

```
http://{webpage address}?v={number}
```

Then replace previous `number` with a new one to force telegram update `og` data.

For example use this:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage?v=3
```

Instead of:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage
```

Comment: The bot that worked for me is @WebpageBot (the one in lowercase doesn't answer)

Comment: The patterns dosent worked for me, but the bot done it right, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore! [Jan 2024]

Answer (score 51):

Go to @webpagebot and send the link (up to 10) you want to update.

Comment: It didn't update for me. I sent the command **updatepreview** But it sent the same preview back to me. But url shortener worked fine.

Comment: the same for me. Bot says ''...all is fine" but it isn't  true

Comment: Guys you should restart Telegram client to see updated card

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore! [Jan 2024]

Answer (score 9):

you must chat with `[@webpagebot][1]` both and tell him in chat

```
https://theurlyouwanttoupdate.com /updatepreview
```

Comment: Notice that correct bot name is not webpage but webpagebot instead

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this problem by using [bitly.com](https://bitly.com) and changing url.

Answer (score 0):

Important addition: None of the "meta property" strings (og:site_name, og:title, og:description) should contain the same data. Such strings are not accepted by Telegram bot and therefore Open Graph does not work there. At least that's the way it is at the moment, I tested it today. Maybe someday Telegram will fix it.