# open graph tags for Telegram and joomla3

Tags: facebook, joomla, joomla3.0, facebook-opengraph, telegram

I have joomla 3 and I have problem with Open Graph tags.
I use "Global open Graph" Plugin to make OG tags on my site! 
but the tags are static and dont change! (others site have different OG contents on different articles ! ).
[problem with OG tags on joomla and telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MenVd.jpg).
my codes:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.takidea.ir" />
<meta property="og:title" content="مرکز تحقیقات کارآفرین (تک)" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="مرکز تحقیقات کارآفرین (تک)" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="مرکز تحقیقات کارآفرین (تک) ارائه دهنده خدمات مالکیت فکری ، ثبت اختراع ، مالکیت فکری ، دانش بنیانی و ..." />
<meta property="og:locale" content="fa_IR" />
```

this Tags only works on facebook.
what should I do to have a preview of my contents on "Telegram" ???

sorry for my bad English!

Comment: duplicate question:
check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707915/how-clear-cache-open-graph-data-of-url-in-telegram

Answer (score 1):

Use @WebPageBot to force update your webpage data in Telegram.