# Do I really need xmlns or prefix to use opengraph meta tags?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, xml-namespaces

On http://ogp.me it's suggested that I use:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Confusingly, on that same page they link to an article about [technical design decisions](https://www.scribd.com/doc/30715288/The-Open-Graph-Protocol-Design-Decisions) that uses this:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

I took a look at the source for **facebook.com**, **twitter.com**, and **stackoverflow.com** and all use Opengraph meta tags but none include any xmlns or prefix declaration.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is basically a rehash of answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943451/meaning-of-html-prefix-attribute-open-graph-protocol) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687/open-graph-namespace-declaration-html-with-xmlns-or-head-prefix).
You should specify a namespace with the `prefix` attribute (newer, more recommended method) or the `xmlns` declaration (equivalent; an older reminiscent of xhtml). For Opengraph metatags, however, you may choose to omit the prefix/declarations as [Opengraph (among others)](https://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1#crawl) is widely recognized:

> RDFa users can use these prefixes without having the obligation of
>   defining the prefixes in the HTML code

In spite of that, explicit is better than implicit, as they say in our profession. It is better to announce you are using Opengraph metatags then just use them and expect whoever reading the tags to infer that based on the experience that "oh, if I ever see the 'og' prefix, it probably stands for Opengraph" – although most people will do just that. The suggestion to declare a prefix is a very good one and you *should* follow it. One of the reasons is that it will make it easier to distinguish Opengraph 'og' tags than other, future 'og' tags that might be more popular in the future.

To conclude, you may choose any of the three methods: `prefix`, `xmlns` or nothing at all, with preference to the first.

Comment: This sentence is confusing to me "*RDFa users can use these prefixes without having the obligation of defining the prefixes in the HTML code*".  What exactly is an "RDFa user"?  How are they different from anyone else?

Comment: 1. You are the RDFa user, as the author of the HTML you are intending on writing.

2. I'll edit the answer and try to justify the suggestion to _use_ a prefix.

Comment: thanks for explaining.  I guess it's a little like saying, "kitchen users can use the sink without having the obligation to wash their dishes".  Might as well just say "everyone/anyone can use these prefixes"... but now I get it.

Comment: Well, admittedly I use the kitchen sink without washing the dishes, but it's not something I'm proud of :)