# OpenGraph prefix in header necessary?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I found many ways to declare opengraph. But which one is the "right" way?

http://ogp.me/ use in source code

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

but in examples the html-tag instead:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

combination with facebook look like

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

or without prefix

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

ogp.me link to imdb as example that use it this way

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

another sites set the og:type "website" or "article" inline like

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
```

ogp.me link zu a doc:
https://de.scribd.com/doc/30715288/The-Open-Graph-Protocol-Design-Decisions
See page 15; It said don't use this form?

```
 xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
```

So much combinations, another websites do nothing of it and only use simple the meta-tags. Is the declaration optional or which one should I use in which form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` is the required prefix for open graph protocol meta tags.

`xmlns` is an attribute for XML namespaces, more about that here:
[[Open Graph namespace declaration: HTML with XMLNS or head prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687/open-graph-namespace-declaration-html-with-xmlns-or-head-prefix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687/open-graph-namespace-declaration-html-with-xmlns-or-head-prefix)

---

You can set it on the `<html>` or `<head>` element as you like, the difference is the scope of the prefix. There is no benefit in limiting it to `<head>` even though in most cases you will only use the related `<meta>` tags inside `<head>`.

---

The `fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"` part of the prefix that you have seen sites use is if you want to extend to use Facebook's own properties using "fb:" instead of "og:".

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties

---

This should be perfectly fine to use:

```
<html lang="{lang}" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
     ...
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"><!-- "og:type" can be omitted for 'website' (is default), required for other types: http://ogp.me/#types -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
    <meta property="og:title" content="...">
    <meta property="og:description" content="...">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/path/to/image.png">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
    <meta property="og:image:alt" content="...">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="...">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="...">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="...">
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```